# Subsetting a dataframe using %in% and ! in R

Tags: r, subset

I have the following dataframe.

`Test_Data <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c("d", "e", "f"), z = c("g", "h", "i"))`

```
  x y z
1 a d g
2 b e h
3 c f i
```

I would like to filter it based on multiple conditions. Specifically, I would like to remove any record that has the value of "b" in column x or "f" in column y. My subsetted result would be;

```
  x y z
1 a d g
```

I tried the following solutions;

```
View(Test_Data %>% subset(!x %in% "b" | !y %in% "f"))
View(Test_Data %>% subset(!x %in% "b" & !y %in% "f"))
View(Test_Data %>% subset(!(x %in% "b" | y %in% "f")))
```

The last two solutions give me the result I want, however the first one is the only one that makes 'sense' to me because it uses the OR operator and I only need one of the conditions to be met. Why do the last solutions work but not the first?

Comment: TRUE|FALSE or FALSE|TRUE returns TRUE

Comment: for the first two, why would you expect `a OR b` and `a AND b` to give you the same result?

Comment: This is basically about understanding [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) about the negation of logical operators. I'm not sure what to say other than your under instinct about what makes "sense" is just off in this case.

Comment: The second one needs paranthesis ie `(!x %in% "b") & (!y %in% "f")`

Comment: The first two solutions: I did not expect them to give me the same result. I tried the first and it didn't work and tried using 'AND' instead of 'OR' which worked but I couldn't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The subset operation returns the rows that you want to KEEP.

However your set of rules defines the rows you want NOT TO KEEP. Therefore you're getting confused with the negation logic.

The rows you don't want to keep follow a series of rules: r1 | r2 | ....
The NEGATION is: !(r1 | r2 | ...), or: !r1 & !r2 & ...

Comment: Are you certain about that? In R, the tilde `~` generates a *formula*, not negation. I'm used to seeing `!` for negation.

Comment: @r2evans I was using logical notation. I changed to R as you pointed out, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm familiar with the notation, I believe many users asking questions here about [tag:r] may not be as intimately familiar with it and may actually try it. I'm not opposed to using `~` is long as you are clear that that is meant to be pseudo-code notation, not literal R notation. Thanks for the edit :-)

Comment: @r2evans I agree, it came out of habit...